# How can I find word in Excel and delete the digit Before?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I would like to split the word. If i found ACC, The word before ACC is delete in vba code

[image]

I found this code but it will delete the word after the found text

```
Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content
myRange.Find.Execute FindText:="blue", _
    Forward:=True
If myRange.Find.Found = True Then 
myRange.SetRange (myRange.End + 1), ActiveDocument.Content.End
myRange.Delete
```

If it possible can use formula function ?  Please suggest

Comment: You can also make it more dynamic using the formula, instead of hardcoding the word `ACC` --> `=REPLACE(A1,1,MAX(IFERROR(FIND(CHAR(ROW($65:$90)),A1)-1,""))-1,)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this formula (instead of VBA):

`=MID(A1,FIND("ACC",A1),LEN(A1))`

Btw: the code you posted is for Word-VBA - not for Excel-VBA

Answer (score 1):

If you'd want to do it with a formula, you can use

`=IFERROR(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("ACC",A1)+1),"")`
(though Mid is less typing and more used nowadays because of it, just giving you options :p)

and if you'd want to use VBA:

```
Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, arr, lRow As Long
    Dim srchStr As String
    srchStr = "ACC"
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lRow = ws.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = ws.Range("D1:D" & lRow)
    arr = rng.Value
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        If InStr(arr(i, 1), srchStr) Then
            arr(i, 1) = Mid(arr(i, 1), InStr(arr(i, 1), srchStr))
        Else
            arr(i, 1) = ""
        End If
    Next i
    rng.Offset(, 1).Value = arr
End Sub
```

That should do it as well.